# Asymptotic of $T(n) = T(n-2) + \frac{1}{ \lg n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Trying to determine asymptotic of

$$T(n) = T(n-2) + \displaystyle\frac{1}{ \lg n}$$
$$\lg n = \log_{2}n $$

Last term $\frac{1}{ \lg n}$  give me a lot of trouble. Iterative method doesn't work. Tried change of variables, there is nothing to change.

Comment: What is the $\lg$ function? Natural logarithm?

Comment: @RodCarvalho It is log base 2 (binary log)

Comment: @newprint You should accept the answer that you find most useful. You have not accepted answers to any of your questions so far, even though they seem like good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You can bound $T(n)$ between $\frac 12 \sum_{i=4}^n \frac 1{\lg i}$ and $\frac 12 \sum_{i=4}^n \frac 1{\lg (i-2)}$ (to within a small correction), each of which is close to the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) $\int \frac 1{\ln x}\; dx$, which goes as $\frac x{ \ln x}$ (like yours to within factors of $\ln 2$)

Comment: Might want to check those small values of $i$ in your sums...

Comment: The integral of 1/lnx is an infinite series, Then how can we deduce it to be x/lnx?

Comment: @VK:  See the [asymptotic expansion of the logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion)